# Protovis and .net winform application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-visualization, protovis

I want to display and use Protovis data visualization control in Winform/WPF windows application. Can anybody help me how to do this in .net?

Thanks in advance.

Best Regards,
Omkar

Comment: Are you aware that Protovis is a _JavaScript_ library, designed to be run in a browser?

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. After I Googled for some time, I found that this can be done if we could host web browser in .net. However, bad news is IE does not support protovis. I am planning to use Mozilla ActiveX in WPF but it also has some issues.

Answer (score 0):

I would think your best bet for your question is to host a browser that is capable of displaying Protovis.  In other words, not IE (currently).  You could go Mozilla, WebKit, and likely other options too.  Alternatively, you may consider Adobe Air.  I don't know if what you are trying to do is possible with Air though.

Good luck.